# How to update UI without requesting api for data

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I want to build dynamic chat app.
I want to update users activity status. I can do this with backend requests every x seconds.

But for example Discord can do this without any requests (nothing in network tab in Chrome).

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Discord uses [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket). You can see them in the network tab if you go to the "ws" section under "Network"

Comment: *"But for example Discord can do this without any requests (nothing in network tab in Chrome)."* I suspect you're mistaken about that, as it would require magic for Discord to update the displayed status of a remote user without network traffic. :-) More likely you're missing a [websocket connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) made at page load and left open, so the page can talk to the server without *establishing* a new connection to do so (because it can use the web socket that's already open).

Comment: You need to use WebSocket or Server side events to handle the scenario. Socket.io is good library to explore for client as well as server side. https://elevateprogramming.blogspot.com

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For this type of requests it's the server who sends the response to the client without requesting in a stream
not the usual HTTP requests where the client request something and the server sends the response so it's either you use SSE (server-sent-event) unidirectional tunnel or you use a socket which is bidirectional tunnel (socket.io for example) but for this need sse are better so you don't need to check every x seconds the server notifies the clients subscribed to this tunnel it's like a notification

check these links:
[server-sent-event-1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)
[server-sent-event-2](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)

Comment: *"...but for this need sse are better so you don't need to check every x seconds..."* That isn't how web sockets work. You don't have to do polling.

Comment: that's what i said you don't have to send requests every x seconds

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).